# Racket language change & module problems

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I'm trying to implement some of SICP graphic programs in Racket, but there are 2 problems:

When I need to use 'let' I can't use beginner language.
When I try to change language, or open new file while using "advanced" language, I get this error:

```
module: identifier already imported from a different source
```

error when I try to load image module by (require 2htdp/image).

What's going on? Also, are there better ways to train with images in Scheme?

Comment: Consider not using student languages anymore (I know you are using 2htdp, but `#lang racket` and others just open the door to much more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Óscar mentions, you are better off with using `#lang planet neil/sicp`, However, if you want to import somethng that exports identical symbols you can prefix them:

```
(require (prefix-in hi: 2htdp/image))
```

Then all exported from that have prefix hi:, eg. `(hi:circle 30 "outline" "red")`. The colon isn't anything special. The prefix could have been `xxx` and it would be `xxxcircle`.

Also, you can only import the symbols you want:

```
; you only want circle and eclipse
(require (only-in 2htdp/image circle ellipse))
```

Or you can import everything except some symbols:

```
; everything except circle and ellipse
(require (except-in 2htdp/image circle))
```

And there is no reason not using `racket` or `racket/base` as language when you know this.

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear why you want to use `2htdp/image` in the first place. A much more useful package to use would be Neil Van Dyke's [SICP Support page](http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/), it provides a language with support for the book *and* includes the graphical language. That should be enough to solve both of your problems.

Comment: Tried that... I get "tcp-connect : forbiden client access to planet.racket-lang.org:80

Comment: There's a problem with your network, check with the system administrator... or try connecting elsewhere